# How do I put an Ethereum address in an HTML link?

Tags: metamask, addresses

I'm sure I've seen this done, but I cannot for the life of me remember where. I'm writing a simple HTML page, and on it I'd like to have an Ethereum address as a clickable link, so people with Web3.0-enabled browsers can interact with it e.g., to send some Ether to it. I'm familiar with how to create links to other pages, images, etc. but I don't even know where to start researching this particular case, and many, many hours of searching hasn't yielded anything useful.

I'm familiar with Ethereum and how it works, but basically I just can't seem to figure out where to start to get it onto a web page. Can anyone at least point me in the right direction, where I can learn what I need to know?

Comment: Metamask docs might be a good place to start https://docs.metamask.io/guide/

Comment: this is not a help response. @atomh33ls

Answer (score 0):

For bitcoin you can do `<a href="bitcoin:address">address</a>`

For nimiq you can do: `<a href="https://wallet.nimiq.com/nimiq:address">address</a>`

I have not seen a way to do it with ethereum.

Answer (score 0):

https://app.ens.domains/

Currently, registration costs are set at the following prices:
5+ character .eth names: $5 in ETH per year.
4 character .eth names: $160 in ETH per year.
3 character .eth names $640 in ETH per year.
3 and 4 character names have 'premium' pricing to reflect the small number of these names available.
Also, if the name was previously owned by someone but recently released, it has a temporary decreasing premium to prevent squatters snatching up names.